# How can I prompt the user to reboot in a .NET installation?

Tags: c#, .net, installation, windows-installer

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 to write an installation, and I'm a completely new to installations. I've created an installation and successfully written some custom actions using a C# assembly. One action sets a RunOnce registry value, and now I need to prompt the user to reboot when the installation finishes, but I have no idea how. I've read the Installer class documentation, but I can't find any mention of rebooting.

I'm assuming I need to somehow get down to being able to call MsiSetProperty and set a REBOOT property, but I don't know how to do that from my [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) installer project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks. I ended up using a post-build event to run a batch file with the following command. The hard part was tracking down WiRunSQL.vbs, which was in the ["Windows SDK Components for Windows Installer Developers"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370834(VS.85).aspx) download.

```
cscript "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0\Samples\SysMgmt\MSI\scripts\WiRunSQl.vbs" my.msi "INSERT INTO `Property`(`Property`, `Value`) VALUES ('REBOOT', 'F')"
```

Comment: Thank you for finally showing me where that stupid script is located! I've been searching for over an hour.

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing your installer using [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX), you need to add this:

```
<ScheduleReboot After="InstallFinalize"/>
```

If you're using the cut-down "Installer" project in [Visual Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio), I'm not sure... But this link [here](http://www.omgili.com/newsgroups/microsoft/public/windows/msi/3CCCF4FC-564D-43D7-ACFD-26444AA72126microsoftcom.html) suggests a [CScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host#Available_scripting_engines) command that seems to show how to inject an MSI property into the installer project, much as you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the property in the MSI initally, rather than trying to update it at runtime.

Visual Studio 2008 ships with WiX anyway, see *[Visual Studio ships the WiX toolset](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/11/26/Visual-Studio-ships-the-WiX-toolset)* for more details. That said, I'm not a Visual Studio 2008 user, so I don't know if that's in addition, or in replacement to the previous Visual Studio setup projects.